# Core data. Invalid concurrent access to managed object calling 'release'

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, core-data, afnetworking

I am using `GDCoreDataConcurrencyDebugging` and I do not fully understand the error I get. I Use `AFNetworking` to fetch some data, and in the success block I save the response in Core Data.

I can get the error with the following code:

```
NSURL *baseURL = ...
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[operationManager GET:@"layouts"
           parameters:nil
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

                   // backgroundManagedObjectContext is of NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType
                   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [AppDelegate backgroundManagedObjectContext];

                  [context performBlock:^{

                      // Fetch and modify some NSManagedObject 
                      NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Layout"];                          
                      Layout *layout  = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil][0];

                      // Remove this and the error goes away
                      layout.name = @"foo";                          

                      // Or this, and the error goes away
                      [context save:nil];

                  }];
              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){}];
```

The error message from `GDCoreDataConcurrencyDebugging` is the following:

```
Invalid concurrent access to managed object calling 'release'; Stacktrace: (
0   Econ                                0x000000010016fba3 ValidateConcurrency + 346
1   Econ                                0x000000010016f85c CustomSubclassRelease + 18
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035718eb CFRelease + 603
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103580a82 __CFBasicHashDrain + 322
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010357180c CFRelease + 380
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035a2c4d -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 157
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102ff128e _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 236
7   Foundation                          0x0000000101261e0b -[NSConcreteNotification dealloc] + 84
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102ff128e _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 236
9   Econ                                0x0000000100022e8b __destroy_helper_block_426 + 59
10  libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib          0x000000010608a734 _Block_release + 196
11  CoreData                            0x0000000100abbb61 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 433
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106010614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105ff8a1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1664
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036031f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035c4dcb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035c4366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000105818a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
18  UIKit                               0x0000000101cd1900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
19  Econ                                0x00000001000a28ef main + 111
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106044145 start + 1
21  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like your background managed object context is perhaps busy with something else.

Comment: It shouldn't be, but if so, how would it explain the error message?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is resulting from accessing your managed object `Layout` in a background thread. It also seems that your `Layout` object has been released by the time you are accessing it.

Having had a look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/performBlock:) it seems that the method `performBlock:` has the following discussion:

> You use this method to send messages to managed objects if the context was initialized using *NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType* or *NSMainQueueConcurrencyType*. This method encapsulates an autorelease pool and a call to processPendingChanges.

I think the key here is the fact that `perfomBlock:` *encapsulates an autorelease pool*. Autorelease pools are designed to aggressively release all the objects within, add this to a concurrent situation and you could get strange behaviour. If you notice there is a call to `_Block_release` made by the system in your stack trace, this could be the culprit. I'm not entirely sure but I believe that the `performBlock:` method queues the block and then executes it whenever it's convenient for the context (hence *asynchronous*). It's possible that the system is releasing key resources before your block has a chance to run.

I would try using either [`performBlockAndWait:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/performBlockAndWait:) which is a *synchronous* call, and there is no mention of autorelease pools in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/performBlockAndWait:). Or, performing the code on the main thread using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{})` using a standard `NSManagedObjectContext`. Or just forget the call to `performBlock:`.

Comment: I think the issue is that the the `NSManagedObject`s that I work on in the background context, are released from another thread. Therefore the warning about `release`.  I would think that the autorelease pool of `performBlock:` would release the objects in the background thread. Using `performBlockAndWait:` is not an option, as this is for fetching large amounts of data in the background.

Comment: The success block runs on the main thread. Modifying the layout.name and calling `save:` must be done in `performBlock:`